# Can I give a table tennis ball enough spin so that it rolls further on the other side instead of bouncing?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

If I give a table tennis ball enough topspin, is it possible that the ball on touching the other side of the table doesn´t bounce, but just rolls further?

Comment: yes its possible in real situation....one should try to  define the conditions under which it happens.

Comment: If you are a table-tennis player, have you tried to get this effect? Whether or not it is possible can more easily be answered by asking a table-tennis player rather than a physicist.  A physicist can only offer an explanation.

Comment: I played it a lot and when I made a great topspin ball, the ball, when it came on the other side of the table, shoot forward in a lower trajectory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Firstly, suppose the ball is moving with a velocity $v$ prior to collision then its post-collision velocity will be

$$ v^\prime = v - (1+e)v\cdot\hat{n} $$

where $e$ is the coefficient of restitution and $\hat{n}$ the surface normal. Note that this is independent of the spin of the ball.

If the materials were such that $e=0$ (e.g. you covered the table with glue) then we can stop the ball from bouncing. However, that's obviously cheating.

So the only way to prevent a bounce, i.e. $v^\prime\cdot\hat{n}=0$, is if the vertical velocity prior to collision is also zero, i.e. $v\cdot\hat{n}=0$.

Fortunately, there is a way to achieve this: the Magnus effect! If you hit the ball downward and with backspin then the Magnus force will counter gravity. And if you get just the right amount of backspin then you could make the ball travel horizontally at the point of contact with the table.

Comment: Can´t the effect occur the other way around? If the ball has enough spin (and a vertical velocity), isn´t it possible that the vertical kinetic energy gets absorbed at the collision point by the ball´s friction, and subsequently rolls further without bouncing?

Comment: Friction absorbs the balls vertical kineic energy?. This must be science fiction. Because friction never counters the vertical motion of the ball(other than drag forces of air and all).As i said the spin dosent affect the normal reaction in the ideal case, but yes as @lemon said, magnus effect can be used.

Comment: As soon as the spinning ball hits the table it starts to spin against the table, in which process friction energy is released.

Comment: I now see that you are of course right. The moment the ball starts to spin against the table the spin is lessened, but the vertical velocity will still be there (in reversed motion), though the ball can shoot forward without reaching the original height (ignoring all other interactions).

Answer (score 0):

The normal reaction force is independent of the angular velocity of the ball and depends from which height youre dropping the ball.  The impulsive friction speeds it up. So the fact whether it bounces or not should be independent of spin.